# Prove: $\|x\|^2=\sum_{i=1}^k|\langle x,e_i\rangle|^2\iff x\in\operatorname{span}\{e_1,\ldots,e_k\}$

Tags: linear-algebra, proof-writing, solution-verification, orthonormal

> Let $\{e_1,\ldots,e_k\}$ be an orthonormal set in a unitary space $V$. Prove:
>   $$\|x\|^2=\sum\limits_{i=1}^k|\langle x,e_i\rangle|^2\iff x\in\operatorname{span}\{e_1,\ldots,e_k\}$$

**My attempt:**

My concerns are precision and conciseness of my proof, as well as deduction and order of conclusions.

$\color{brown}{\Rightarrow}$

Let $M=\operatorname{span}\{e_1,\ldots,e_k\}$. Since $\{e_1,\ldots,e_k\}$ is an orthonormal set, $\implies\{e_1,\ldots,e_k\}$ is an orthonormal basis for $M$. Therefore, according to [this post regarding the *Parseval's identity*](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/402360/721644) , the statement simply follows from the proof given in the answer by @MattL. :
$$\|x\|^2=\langle x,x\rangle=\sum_{i=1}^k\langle x, e_i \rangle \overline {\langle x, e_i \rangle}=\sum_{i=1}^k|\langle x,e_i\rangle|^2$$
$\color{brown}{\Leftarrow}$

Having in mind $M^\perp:=\{z\in V\mid\langle y,z\rangle=0,\ \forall y\in M\}, M\oplus M^\perp=V$, we can write: $x=y+z, y\in M,z\in M^\perp$.

Then:
$$\|x\|^2=\langle x, x\rangle=\langle y+z, y+z\rangle=\langle y,y\rangle+\underbrace{\langle z,y\rangle}_{0} +\underbrace{\langle y,z\rangle}_{0} +\langle z,z\rangle=\langle y,y\rangle+\langle z,z\rangle\tag 1$$

Then:
$$y=\sum_{i=1}^k\langle y,e_i\rangle e_i=\sum_{i=1}^k\langle x-z,e_i\rangle e_i=\sum_{i=1}^k(\langle x,e_i\rangle-\langle z,e_i\rangle) e_i=\sum_{i=1}^k\langle x,e_i\rangle e_i\tag 2$$
Now,from $(1)\ \&\ (2)$ we obtain: $\color{Maroon}{\langle z,z\rangle=0}$ and, therfore, $\color{blue}{x=y\in M}$

May I ask if this is legitimate and what I could do to improve my proof?

**P. S.** I've seen some posts dealing with similar problems, but most of them include *Hilbert spaces* which we haven't learned yet. Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You  can directly verify that $\|x-\sum\limits_{i=1}^{k} \langle x, e_i \rangle e_i\|^{2}=0$ by just expanding the left side and using definition of inner product.

Comment: Then, if we consider $x'=x-\sum\langle x,e_i\rangle e_i,$ $$ \langle x',x'\rangle=\left\langle x-\sum\langle x,e_i\rangle e_i,x-\sum\langle x, e_j\rangle e_j\right\rangle$$ $$=\langle x,x\rangle-\sum\limits_j\overline{\langle x,e_j\rangle}\langle x,e_j\rangle-\sum\limits_i\langle x,e_i\rangle\underbrace{\langle e_i, x\rangle}_{\overline{\langle x,e_i\rangle}}+\sum\limits_{ij}\langle x,e_i\rangle\overline{\langle x,e_j\rangle}\underbrace{\langle e_i,e_j\rangle}_{\delta_{ij}}=\langle x,x\rangle-\sum|\langle x,e_i\rangle|^2$$ $\implies x'=0\ \&\ x\in\operatorname{span}\{e_1,\ldots,e_k\}$?

Comment: @Cheesecake Yes that is correct.